# Why is simple seq2seq in pytorch always returning NaN?

Tags: pytorch, seq2seq

I have the following trimmed down model:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
import argparse
import torch
import torch.utils.data
from torch import nn, optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn import functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torchvision.utils import save_image
import json
import numpy as np
import datetime
import os


class EncoderRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size=8, hidden_size=10, num_layers=2):
        super(EncoderRNN, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

        #initialize weights
        nn.init.xavier_uniform(self.lstm.weight_ih_l0, gain=np.sqrt(2))
        nn.init.xavier_uniform(self.lstm.weight_hh_l0, gain=np.sqrt(2))

    def forward(self, input):
        tt = torch
        print input.shape
        h0 = Variable(tt.FloatTensor(self.num_layers, input.size(0), self.hidden_size))
        c0 = Variable(tt.FloatTensor(self.num_layers, input.size(0), self.hidden_size))
        encoded_input, hidden = self.lstm(input, (h0, c0))
        encoded_input = self.sigmoid(encoded_input)
        return encoded_input

train_x = torch.from_numpy(np.random.random((2000,19,8))).float()


train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_x,
    batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

model = EncoderRNN()

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-6)

optimizer.zero_grad()


loss_function = torch.nn.BCELoss(reduce=True)

def train(epoch):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    for batch_idx, (data_x) in enumerate(train_loader):
        x = model(Variable(data_x))
        print("output has nan: " + str(np.isnan(x.detach().numpy()).any()))


train(0)
```

To summarize, I think I'm basically just feeding an input into an LSTM with random initialized hidden values, and then taking the sigmoid of the output of that LSTM.  Then I'm feeding that output to a decoder LSTM, and taking the sigmoid of the output of the decoder output and using that as my final value.

Unfortunately, even in the first iteration, the model often outputs a vector of the correct shape (batch_size, seq_length, seq_dim), but contains at least one and sometimes all NaN values.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

What I've tried so far:

- changing LSTM to GRU
- changing sigmoid to relu
- changing the dimension of the hidden representation
- getting the failing input down to the encoder

Edit: Apologies to everyone who tried to help when I had broken code - I really do value your time, and thanks so much for helping!

Comment: Could you provide the a complete example that can be run and reproduces your problem? Are there `NaN`s before the the BCELoss?  Are there any `NaN`s in the `encoded_input`? Come on man, you can debug a bit yourself first!

Comment: sure, I thought that we were supposed to minimize the amount of code in the question, but I'd be happy to provide more

Comment: [Complete, but minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ;-)

Comment: Mh.. I'm getting no `NaN` values at all when trying your code. I tried several times though  (pytorch 0.4.0, numpy 1.15.4) - Maybe you could give it a try on a another system with other than your current ones versions.

Comment: I tried on another server without any problems!  In my case that's fine enough - is there a way to close this question?

Comment: You can just add an answer (ideally with some more detail than in your comment :) yourself and accept it.

Comment: @lightning so is this a machine related problem ? I am running on a Mac and face the same issues.

Comment: @SiddhantTandon my best guess is either machine-related or related to version of pytorch being used

Comment: @lightning thanks for the reply. could you solve this problem anyway ? I am using `1.1.0.post2` version right now.